# executeQuery is always empty

Tags: java, connection, derby

I'm trying to get  the data from database but get nothing. The problem is

> ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(readQuery);

always empty. And

> while (resultSet.next())

is never executing.
Would really appreciate any help

```
public class DB {

    public Connection connect() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DB;create=true;user=user;password=password";
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return connection;
    } 

    ArrayList read(Connection connection, String table, String column, String value) {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList();  
        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String readQuery = "select * from " + table + " where " + column + " = '" + value + "'";

            out.print(readQuery);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(readQuery); 

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int numberOfColumns = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
                out.print("Read\n");
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
                    results.add(resultSet.getString(i));   
                }
            }
            statement.close(); 
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {   
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post more of your stacktrace and indicate which line it fails on.

Comment: As I asked before, please post your stacktrace.

Comment: so this code is not where the error is.  see User.java:61

Comment: .... and what did you find?

Comment: I can not see where the exception is thrown, but never just ignore exceptions, so add a message in `catch (SQLException ex) {   
        }`

Comment: If `ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(readQuery);` is returnign null, then you should get a NPE at `while (resultSet.next())`

Comment: The line 61 fails because of the null value it has to compare due to problem somewhere here. I updated the question again. The problem: resultSet is always null. Maybe there's something wrong with the connection?

Comment: add the message in the sqlexception.

Comment: Also according to javadoc `Returns:
a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; never null`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for mistake in the wrong place. Will need to check the rest of the code I guess

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. Could you please explain why the executeQeury always returns no results. When I print it's always: "[]". Not null but empty. When I try to run query inside the database it returns result it has to but when I try to run it from this piece of code it doesn't return the record.

Comment: Not quite sure, could it be that you need the table and column names to be lowercase?

Comment: exactly same query is running as a single procedure. Through I tried both uppercase and lowercase. Same not working

Comment: Please LOG the SqlException.

Comment: I removed the part which were causing errors. I don't get the errors anymore but The resultSet is simply returning "[]"